# Is it possible to center an element that's wider than its parent and absolutely positioned without Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**BASE HTML/CSS - JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/tae8pc1g/2/

All in the title really. All the important code in the JSFiddle is as follows:

```
<div class="example-button">Menu Button
    <ul class="example-menu">
        <li>This is</li>
        <li>some example</li>
        <li>dynamic</li>
        <li>content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.example-button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.example-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Using HTML & CSS only, is it possible to center `.example-menu` relative to the width of `.example-button` even if it is wider than `.example-button`?

Comment: when you want it without javascript, why is js and jquery in the tags? :)

Comment: is `example-menu`'s width fixed?

Comment: @Alex I guess because it's relevant, there might not be a solution without Javascript. `.example-menu`'s width ideally would not be fixed, although for the purposes of finding a solution it can be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible using:

**1-** For unknown width:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

**2-** For known width:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -(width/2)
```

Here a working [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/xy7mxydk/2/) to play with

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

.example-button {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

.example-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 100%;
    background: blue;
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px 70px;
    list-style: none;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="example-button">Menu Button
    <ul class="example-menu">
        <li>Please</li>
        <li>center</li>
        <li>me!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ugh... how did I not think of that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It may be considered a hack but using pure CSS you can put this on your example-button class :

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/08fqfhum/

**Note:** this won't work on older browsers (IE8) since it uses CSS transforms. And for some browsers like Safari you would need to add a prefixed version of the transform property too :

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
```