# How to horizontally center a div which is wider than the mobile screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Targeting mobile screens only, I want a circular `div` element which is wider than the mobile screen and is centred. This `div` must be an exact circle.

I've got this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AjitZero/o856s2fL/) but I can't increase the width to be greater than the screen width.

I'm calculating the width based on the `div` height if the height is greater than the screen width. Otherwise, the width should have some minimum value greater than the current screen width.

I'm looking for a `JavaScript`-only solution (no jQuery), if possible. This question is a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399347/is-it-possible-to-center-an-element-thats-wider-than-its-parent-and-absolutely) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399347/is-it-possible-to-center-an-element-thats-wider-than-its-parent-and-absolutely) but I specifically need the `#circle` element to be wider than the screen and using `position: absolute` (as suggested in one of the answers over there) would cause a lot of chaos.

Comment: just create a container to this circle, put at container overflow: hidden; this should work. now in the container put width: 100% and in your circle width: inherit; https://jsfiddle.net/qenfobkv/

Comment: @Leandro your jsfiddle isn't working. The `width: 100%` constricts the circle to within the screen. I wanted to achieve what the answer by @Johannes does. Plus it should be a perfect circle.

Comment: oh ok, sorry, i will fix it even if you got a right answer, is good have more than one asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSS only answer should also be okay? You can add these settings to the element in question:

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/asn8mv7o/1/

Comment: That is what I wanted to achieve, though I how do I restrict the inner `<p>` to have a maximum width equal to the screen width. Also, the JavaScript was to have the same width & height regardless of the screen size.

Comment: You can use a fixed px width as well

Comment: Using a fixed px width would make things easier but I was considering a more responsive solution with variable sized circular `div`s. I think the Js would work now, with the `left: 50%`

Comment: you just wrote "regardless of the screen size" (?)

Comment: Yes, the width was meant to be calculated while keeping `height: auto`, it would depend on how much content, text and/or button(s), are placed in it. A single line would implement a minimum radius `div` while a large paragraph with greater height would scale the width with it. That was what the JavaScript was for.